# SerialBT.readString() save as string

Tags: c, json, string, arduino, esp32

I'm sending a String from my android device to esp32, I want to store SerialBT.readString() value to a string variable, but it's stored as an empty string, what should I do?

```
if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.println(SerialBT.readString()); // this prints the message as well
    String ts=SerialBT.readString();
        Serial.println(ts); // prints nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first call to `SerialBT.readString()` consumes the available data. Your second call will not re-read the same string.

Remove the line:

```
Serial.println(SerialBT.readString()); // this prints the message as well
```