# convert uint_8 ascii to string

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I am sending a string from RaspberryPi to ESP32 via BT.I am getting an ascii values one per line. How to convert it into a whole one String? I tried as follow but I get an error while running the method printReceivedMEssage(buffer):

invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]

```
uint8_t buffer; 

void printReceivedMessage(const uint8_t* buf) {
  char string_var[100];
  size_t bufflen = sizeof(buf);

  for (int i = 0; i < bufflen; ++i) {
    Serial.println(static_cast<char>(buf[i]));
  }

  memcpy( string_var, buf, bufflen );
  string_var[bufflen] = '\0'; // 'str' is now a string
  Serial.print("string_var=");
  Serial.println(string_var);
}

void loop() 
{
  buffer = (char)SerialBT.read();  
  Serial.println(buffer); // THIS SHOWS AN ASCII VALUES ONE PER LINE
  printReceivedMessage(buffer); // ERROR
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I changed it to 4 since the text send by RPi is lenght=4. but it still didnt compile

Comment: @Lundin your comment brings nothing to the question for me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error that should be fixed is the incorrect `sizeof()`.  The code is getting the size of a pointer, which in C and C++ does simply that (you will get the value 4 for 32-bit pointers for example), but **doesn't** return the size of any "contents" being pointed to.  In your case, where the buffer contains a null-terminated string, you can use `strlen()`

```
size_t bufflen = strlen(buf);
```

To remove the compiler error you need to pass a byte array to `printReceivedMessage()`.  For example:

```
uint8_t buffer[200];
```

Also, you could print the buffer in one call with `Serial.println(a_string)`, but then you need to read a whole string with [SerialBT.readString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418969/serialbt-readstring-save-as-string).

The byte array seems to be an unnecessary intermediary.  Just read a String over BT, and print it, as in the post I linked to.

```
Serial.println(SerialBT.readString());
```

Comment: I did not downvote this answer, but it's incomplete. The given code is using `sizeof()` incorrectly. As written, `buf_len` will always be 4, which is `sizeof(uint8_t*)`. This appears to be working because the original poster is sending small numbers. Try sending 88888888 and it will fail. The code should use `strlen()`. `sizeof()` is a compile-time operator which returns the storage used by the time at compile-time and cannot be used find the length of a string at runtime.

Comment: @romkey You're right, missed that.  Edited in a fix for this too. Thanks.

Comment: Kudos to you for coming back and editing an old answer! You're doing better than me with that :)